# flexi search inside the impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex, flexible-search

I want to write an impex to disable an account with an particular user-id which contains the particular email id.
let's say if email xyz@abc.com is associated with the user id xyx then xyz account should be soft disabled (loginDisabled should be true).
For getting the xyz user-id i gonna run the flexi search :

```
    select {emp.uid} as empid from { Employee as emp} where {emp.email} = 'xyz@abc.com'
```

this will return me the user-ids containing the email as xyz@abc.com

and to disable a account i can run the impex as :

```
      UPDATE Employee; UID[unique = true]; groups;loginDisabled[default=true];
      xyz;;true
```

Now i want that both the Felxi serach and impex should be combined and the flexisearch should return the userid and impex part should disable the account, i have tried below impex but it didn't did anything:

```
     UPDATE Employee; UID[unique = true]; groups;loginDisabled[default=true]
     "#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch(""select {emp.uid} as empid from { Employee as emp} where {emp.email} = 'xyz@abc.com'"");"
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I misunderstood the question. I thought you were trying to export the data.

This is how you disable the log-in using impex:

```
UPDATE Employee;uid[unique=true];loginDisabled[default=true]
;xyz@abc.com;
```

Comment: UPDATE Employee;PK[unique=True];groups(uid);loginDisabled[default=true]
"#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch("" SELECT {emp.pk} FROM { Employee AS emp} WHERE {emp.email} = 'xyz@abc.com' "");"
i have run this impex still no effect

Comment: @arvindpanchal Add a new line after "loginDisabled[default=true]". It can't be on the same line. If it works, upvote and accept the answer.

Comment: I run the command in separate line only still it didn't worked, Anyways Thanks

Comment: @arvindpanchal What error message or stacktrace are you getting?

Comment: the impex is running successfully but there is not effect for the user the account is not diuabled

Comment: @arvindpanchal I updated the answer. Please upvote and accept if it's what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I tried running

`UPDATE Employee;PK[unique=True];groups(uid);loginDisabled[default=true] "#% impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch("" SELECT {emp.pk} FROM { Employee AS emp} WHERE {emp.email} = 'xyz@abc.com' "");"`

But no luck the impex is running without any issue but does not reflect the changes in backoffice

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using a groovy script instead of flexible search.

The `impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch` is, as the name say used for export only, so you are not be able to use it in import. If you want to use impex, then you should export first using `impex.exportItemsFlexibleSearch`, change the value in the csv, then re-import it again.